# In Scala how to group consecutive elements in array

Tags: arrays, scala

Given

```
scala> val a = (1 to 9).toArray
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

would like to group elements in `a` in this way,

```
Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6), Array(7,8,9))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to get groups by 3 elements you could use method `grouped`:

```
a.grouped(3).toArray
// Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6), Array(7, 8, 9))
```

Comment: for bigger datasets say close to 1000 records its dropping the records ..Any thoughts?